# Why does SMTP email method produce 0x800ccc0b Error

Tags: vba, ms-access, smtp, cdo.message

Using Microsoft Access (VBA) I have the following Email function using reference to the "Microsoft CDO for Windows 2000 Library".

```
Public Sub SendEmail()

    Dim Mail As CDO.Message
    Set Mail = New CDO.Message

    With Mail.Configuration.Fields
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'NTLM method
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smptserverport") = 587
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "FromEmail@gmail.com"
        .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "####"
        .Update
    End With
    
    With Mail
        .To = "ToEmail@Hotmail.com"
        .From = "FromEmail@gmail.com"
        .subject = "Test Email"
        .TextBody = "Testing, please do not reply!"
        .Send
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Whilst on most occasions this will work as expected, I have encountered the below message which I believe is when emails are sent in quick succession.

[image]

This will then freeze up the application preventing other emails from being sent etc until the application is closed completely. What would be best practice to catch when this error occurs to close the object and prevent sending (returning a false boolean value?) allowing the user to reattempt sending the message?

Comment: What is _emails .. sent in quick succession_? Gmail has strict default limitations on messages per batch and per hour/day.

Comment: If for instance the user clicks the button control to send the email 3-4 times in quick succession. I know that this will be a rare scenario however if the app seems unresponsive I have seen users click the button several times in frustration.

Comment: Then, before calling the send function, disable the send button, and, when the send function exits, enable the send button.